# Evaluate integral where $a$ and $b$ are constants

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left( \int_{a}^{b}{f\left(t\right)\mathrm dt} \right)
$$

I understand if say $b=x$ then the answer will be $f(x)$. But what about this situation where a and b are only known to be constants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are both constants, than the integral will evaluate to a constant, so the derivative with respect to x would just be $0$.